# Ties between the Jesuits and the Byzantine?

Tags: history, religious-orders

I am reading into [Society of Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_Jesus), seeking to uncover its parallels and differences with Orthodox Christianity. It is attested the Jesuit order was formed in France on August 15th 1534, by Ignatius de Loyola and approved by Pope Paul III in Rome on September 1540 [[REF](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/jesuit-order-established)] when presented with an outline; unable to uncover this outline, I'm interested in finding the extent in which the order had evangelized according to its Byzantine roots from this point in history on to this present day.

Comment: What's your evidence for any "Byzantine roots"?

Comment: I do ask generally and base on the evidence of being instated by the Pope, who's relations extend well with the Eastern Orthodox Church [(see wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_John_Paul_II%27s_relations_with_the_Eastern_Orthodox_Church).

Comment: @aitía The founder of the Jesuits ([St. Ignatius of Loyola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignatius_of_Loyola)) grew up in the [Crown of Castile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_of_Castile) in the 15th century where Roman Catholicism predominated for centuries earlier.  It's very far from the Byzantine Empire.  Why would the outline has Byzantine roots?